Net Core Shared Cookie Update Claims Across Applications
What is the best approach I can do to achieve the following: I currently have an Authentication API I am using to allow other client applications to reach to login with a cookie. This cookie is being shared among other applications on the same domain such that once someone logs in to one application the cookie can work on the other apps. What I would like to achieve is the ability for one application to update claims through a manual login, have that modify the claims on the cookie, and then every other application updates its own claims when it sees the modified cookie.
Am I thinking about this problem in the right way, and what are some ways to achieve this claims sync across applications using the same cookie?
